# How to plot a figure with a title in Arabic?

Tags: plot, fonts, matlab-figure, arabic

How can I plot a figure with a title in Arabic (in xlable, ylable and legend)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use unicode arabic characters in the MatLab code:

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 100);

plot(x, x)

xlabel('ضڧ ٣ڳ')

ylabel('ض')
```

I just copied/pasted characters from Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block).